# Clustering http sever quandry when server on main and child processes

Tags: node.js, load-balancing

Given the below nodejs code. When I run ab (apache benchmark) tests against localhost:8080 I see only the master process serving the requests. However if I remove the handle to the server from the master process, then I see the forked processes swapping in and out. Is there a good reason for this that I am unaware of ?

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var server = require('http').createServer(function(req,res){
   res.writeHead(200);
   var served = process.env.NODE_WORKER_ID || "master"; 
   console.log("hello world I was served by " + served);
   setTimeout(function () {
     res.end("hello world I was served by " + served);
   }, 1000);
});
if(cluster.isMaster){
  for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
     cluster.fork();
   }
 server.listen(8080);
}else{
  server.listen(8080);
}
```

Comment: small note. This is on a linux machine

Comment: Please tag more carefully. This was not a [tag:cluster-analysis] question, but just classic [tag:load-balancing]. It also probably is more appropriate for serverfault, I guess.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse no it is clearly a problem with NodeJS, not the server itself.

Answer (score 0):

Because NodeJS is processing each requst in 1-5 mseconds and your request is never given to the any child process because the main process is not doing anything, just sleeping. If you test it against hundreds of concurrent connections, you will see the througput gain by clustering. Here, I have made a recent benchmark. http://mustafaakin.wordpress.com/2012/03/19/nodejs-simple-clustering-benchmark/

You can bencmark by using [Apache Benchmark](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html)

Comment: I did use apache benchmark. Using 3000 requests and 150 concurrent. With the above code, the request never hit the forked processes. However if you remove the handle to the server from the main process, they begin to switch across processes.